# How to link 2 list in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, linked-list, sharepoint-2013, custom-lists

I am using Sharepoint 2013. I have an "A" list with a lot of data in 2 column. Column "A1" is the name of the item and "A2" is the ID of the item. In the list "B" there are a lot of columns and the user can create new items. I would like to make the user able to have 2 text (or maybe dropdown) field. If the user starts to write in the "Field1" a list appear and the user can select an element from the "A1" column. If the user selected it, the "Field2" automaticaly filled with the same item's ID from the "A2" column. Or the user can do the same with the "Field2" so if the user choose the ID, the name of the item appears in the "Field1".

In short I would like to add two element by selecting one, but the user is free to choose to use the name or the ID of the item.

Any user friendly method what result the same is good for me.

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **lookup column** in **B list to reference A list**.When user save the data you will have both data.

You can watch from this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORFXaG4M5lI

Comment: Yeah, using lookup column and "add a column to show each of these additional fields" sounds good, but it is create an additional column. So if I use this for both field I ll end up having 4 column, 2-2 with same elements.  It would be perfect if the user always use only the "A1" or "A2" as an input, but I have to let them choose from both "A1" or "A2".